# How to detect relationship among files of a GitHub repository

Tags: github, repository

I want to detect the relationship among files of a repository of GitHub project. I searched for some defined methods or library, while I couldn't find anything for this purpose. Could you please introduce a tool or method for doing it except manually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "relationship among files"?

Comment: For instance, when you use a method written in file A in the code of file B, files A and B have a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You could either:

- code your own code search function ([as in here](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/AC/pages/876052610/How+to+Find+list+of+github+repositories+that+contain+a+string), based on [PyGitHub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub))
- use the [GitHub Navigation code](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/navigating-code-on-github) which, for supported languages repositories, allows you to find all references for a function or method within the same repository by clicking the function or method call in a fil
- Use the [SourceGraph extension](https://about.sourcegraph.com/blog/faster-smoother-github-code-browsing) which does the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think just **Github Navigation Code** meets my requirement. Also, it seems that this tool is manual. I need a library in order to use as a script. For example, such as **PyGitHub** that you introduced which can be used in **Pyhton**.

Comment: Do you know any tools such as **PyGitHub** for this purpose met my explained requirements ?

Comment: @Mehdi https://github.com/google/go-github allows you to generate an executable which will be standalone, and can run without Go or anything else.